# Is it expected from memcpy

Tags: c, memcpy

I have a situtation here,I have three api's working together to printf a long string(512 character).
My first api is used to allocate 512 byte of memory and returned address is 2000 ,After that 2nd api will print the string, it uses memcpy operation in between but now when I returned from this api ,address of allocated block in first api has changed from 2000 to 2012 and 3rd api will free the allocated block using address 2012.

Is it expected behaviour or do 3rd api need to have address 2000 to free the memory block correctly?

Comment: No, that sounds like something is wrong, perhaps an overwrite. If you won't show some code, it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks unwind but I am looking for some kind of generic answer.It would be OK if I don't get specific answer

Comment: Generic Answer: "No, that is not the expected behavior."

Comment: Ok Jongware ,So what kind of issue it cause ,also is it beacause of mempcy ?

Comment: Well, that's impossible to answer in a "generic" way. You should show some code.

Answer (score 2):

No, that sounds as if something is wrong.

It's hard to be more specific without seeing your code.

It sounds like your code does this:

```
void print_something(void)
{
  char *s = allocate_string();
  print_string(s);
  free_string(s);
}
```

Then the value of `s` in the function should never change; the other functions only get `s` *by value*  so they cannot legally change it. Of course a memory overwrite can do whatever.

Comment: Thanks unwind for confirming this point ,I am suspecting this could be because of memcpy and memmov could be the right way to go about it

Comment: As long as we do not know the details on this API, at least the signatures  of the functions (which you are guessing in your example) everything gambling.

Comment: For whatever reason the `print_string()`could take a `char**`and do some heavy realloc/copy/alloc/free/etc stuff ... - which would explain what the OP observers. And `free()`ing address 2012 would be perfectly alright.